# Hagbaha on simchas Torah

Tags: halacha, simchat-torah, hagbah-gelilah

After the hakafos on simchas Torah many shuls who have a big congregation will split up and have simultaneous reading groups so everyone in the shul can get an aliyah (which is the custom). My question is, after each group finishes and each person received an aliyah does that Torah require a hagbaha or since it isn't a main reading then it doesnt require a hagbah. From what I have seen people in general dont do hagbah after such a Torah reading,but why not?